# Am I allowed to show my CV from Stack Overflow Careers as an iframe on my personal blog?

Tags: discussion, jobs, cv

My friend tells me that the Stack Overflow CV URL is too long, and is considering showing the content on his blog with the CV content as an iframe.

My reply to him was that I'm not sure if this is allowed as per Stack Overflow's terms.

So am I wrong? Is this allowed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems OK to me, it's already public information. Not sure if careers uses the same anti-framing JavaScript we do though (for security reasons).